# How to solve an "uninitialized constant Cucumber" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm trying to get one open source application up and running.

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Cucumber
```

I have already tried installing Cucumber with the following line. That dowloaded the ".\vendor\plugins\cucumber\" folder, but that error remains the same.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber.git
```

Please find below the stack trace:

```
D:\BitNami RubyStack projects\spot-us>rake db:create:all --trace
(in D:/BitNami RubyStack projects/spot-us)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Cucumber
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
D:/BitNami RubyStack projects/spot-us/lib/tasks/cucumber.rake:13
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1882
:in `in_namespace'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:910:
in `namespace'
D:/BitNami RubyStack projects/spot-us/lib/tasks/cucumber.rake:12
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails
.rb:9
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails
.rb:9:in `each'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails
.rb:9
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
31:in `require'
D:/BitNami RubyStack projects/spot-us/Rakefile:9
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383
:in `load'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383
:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017
:in `load_rakefile'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068
:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016
:in `load_rakefile'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000
:in `run'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068
:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998
:in `run'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/web/BitNami_RubyStack/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't install cucumber via script/plugin, but as gem.

Comment: How can I check if it is already installed?
Actually I can see cucumber is the "gem list".

Comment: This is my gem list. Cucumber is there, but the problem persists.

D:\BitNami RubyStack projects\spot-us>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
after_commit (1.0.6)
bluecloth (2.0.7)
builder (2.1.2)
capistrano (2.5.18)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
cucumber (0.6.4)
daemons (1.0.10)
....

Comment: thx, the problem is solved. Just was the wrong version of cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and uninstalled cucumber version resolved the issue.

Here is the command

> gem uninstall cucumber -v 3.0.0.pre.1

Now I have version "cucumber (2.4.0, 2.0.2)" and it is working now.